# Jsoup parsing google results

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsoup, web-development-server

I want to grab all the links and thumbnails wherever given from a particular google search. Here is my code.

```
package com.esocial.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class ListLinks {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHWA_enIN609IN609&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=thermodynamics%20cbse";
        System.out.println("Fetching : "+url+"\n\n");

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla").get();

        Elements div = doc.select("div.srg");

        for(Element di : div)
        {
            Elements lists = di.select("li.g");

            for(Element list : lists)
            {
                Element anc = list.select("a").first();
                Element img = list.select("img").first();


                System.out.println("\nLink : "+anc.attr("href")+"\nImage Link : "+img.attr("src")+"\n------------------------------------------\n");

            }
        }   
    }

}
```

But this code is not running properly and does not display results. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract? Also what is `div.srg` (I am not able to find div with such class)? Maybe consider printing content of `doc` before you try to parse it. Also remember that Jsoup is not JavaScript emulator but simple parser, so if some content is generated by JavaScript you will not be able to get parse it.

Comment: It is embedded inside various div. This is the div inside whicch their are lists and then iside those list items their are anchor tags and img tags.
I could be approaching this wrong way since I just started coding in jsoup so please if you can help me in fetching the anchr links and respective img links so that I can create a csv file for those links, that would be great.

Comment: When you print content of `doc` via `System.out.println(doc)` can you find `div` with `srg` class?

Comment: No, I cannot but then printing the doc information is also not showing the links of the google results too, then how I would I parse the google results for any kind of search?

Comment: If expected content is not in `doc` then it is either (1) generated by JavaScrip dynamically by browser, or (2) it wasn't sent to your app because google didn't accept `userAgent("Mozilla")` as valid user agent. You can easily test second case by using more detailed header like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0`. In case of problem described in point one you would need more advanced tool than parser, you would need webdriver like selenium.

Comment: It's working with this link "https://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=%22Yorkshire+Capital%22+&as_oq=fraud+OR+allegations+OR+scam&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=lang_en&cr=countryCA&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=" but not with my original one.

Answer (score 0):

I have also worked on to grab the search result.

To get html page . I requested a post REST call.

```
    // HTTP GET request
private void sendGet(String query, GoogleSearchCallback googleSearchCallback) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<GoogleSearchResult> googleSearchResults = new ArrayList<>();
    String url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" + query + "#q=" + query + "course";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(response.toString());
    Elements links = document.select("a[href]");
    for (Element link : links) {

        String temp = link.attr("href");
        if (temp.startsWith("/url?q=")) {
            Log.i(TAG, "" + temp.replace("/url?q=", "") + "");

            URL tempUrl = new URL(temp.replace("/url?q=", ""));
            String path = tempUrl.getFile().substring(0, tempUrl.getFile().lastIndexOf('/'));
            String base = tempUrl.getProtocol() + "://" + tempUrl.getHost() + path;
            Log.i(TAG, "" + base);
            Log.e(TAG, getDomainName(temp));

            GoogleSearchResult googleSearchResult = new GoogleSearchResult();
            googleSearchResult.setResultLink(base);
            googleSearchResult.setResultTitle(link.text());
            googleSearchResults.add(googleSearchResult);
        }
    }
    googleSearchCallback.onGetGoogleResultSuccess(googleSearchResults);
}

 private String getDomainName(String url) {

    String domainName = "";
    matcher = patternDomainName.matcher(url);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        domainName = matcher.group(0).toLowerCase().trim();
    }
    return domainName;

}

private static Pattern patternDomainName;
private Matcher matcher;
private static final String DOMAIN_NAME_PATTERN = "^(http(s)?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";

static {
    patternDomainName = Pattern.compile(DOMAIN_NAME_PATTERN);
}
```